# python how to efficiently group together terms

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data in the following format:

```
<abc>  <anything2> <anything3>.
<_901>  <first> <something1>.
<_905>  <second> <something2>.
<_910>  <anything> <something3>.
<_901>  <second> <something4>.
<_905>  <first> <something6>.
<_901>  <third> <something5>.
<_905>  <third> <something7>.
```

Now I want to group together all the information corresponding to the first column and (first, second, third) values of second column such that I get aggregated information in the following form:

```
   <abc>  <anything2> <anything3>.
   <_901> <something1> <something4> <something5>.
   <_905> <something6> <something2> <something7>.
   <_910>  <anything> <something3>.
```

I tried to achieve this using python dictionary. But since I have a file of 2 Tera bytes. My procedure is running out of memory and is very inefficient. Is there a faster way in python to achieve this. If yes, then can someone please illustrate with an example?

Comment: Check the documentation for for the `itertools` module, the function you want is `groupby`. Make sure you sort your data by the grouping field, though. In your case, you want to make sure all of the `<_901>` entries appear together in the data set.

Comment: Also, I didn't see the 2TB thing! The itertools library is nice becuase it handles iterators, so you only need to keep one copy of that massive thing in memory. Are you reading this data from SQL?

Comment: @BenDundee Thanks a lot for the replies. I am reading the text from a .txt file which is organized in this form

Comment: Man 2TB is pretty huge. I'd probably read the thing into a SQL DB, and go from there. If you use python, you'll have to read the whole thing into memory first, because there's a sort involved.

Comment: @BenDundee I have a server with 64 GB ram..is there some solution which may help me out.

Comment: @BenDundee Also I dont need to store lines like <abc>  <anything2> <anything3> (which dont have first, second, third) in their second column..I just need to store lines which contain first,second and third in their second column

Comment: Is the file sorted somehow? I mean, you can have a <_901> at the beginning of the file and another <_901> at the very end? if so you may need to do multiple passes on the input file unless there is another type of peculiarity on this data, please provide more info about it like how many times on average a specific <_901> tag will appear on the input file.

Comment: Maybe make temporary files for each tag, then combine them all together for the final file?

Comment: @AliceEverett: It's going to be tough any way you slice it. The data which you don't need--is it most of the file? I'd first go through the 2 TB file line by line, and write only the lines you NEED into a new text file.

Comment: In the third line, is there the information of which number is it?

Comment: Also, is it possible to get `<second>` before `<first>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can try to sort the data using unix tool `sort` (it handles very large files pretty nicely). Then lines with same first and second field will be in continuous block, so that you can iterate through them using a python script and output in your favorite format. An example is given below for the case where you don't want any data which do not have first, second or third in their second column.

```
# merger.py
# this python script takes in a file with sorted lines and gives your output
import sys

prevtag = None
data = ['', '', '']
printed = True
for line in sys.stdin:
    fields = line.strip().split()
    if fields[0] != prevtag:
        if not printed:
            print prevtag, ' '.join(data)
            printed = True
        prevtag = fields[0]
        data = ['', '', '']
    if fields[1] == '<first>':
        data[0] = fields[2]
        printed = False
    if fields[1] == '<second>':
        data[1] = fields[2]
        printed = False
    if fields[1] == '<third>':
        data[2] = fields[2]
        printed = False
if not printed:
    print prevtag, ' '.join(data)
```

Now you can pipe the output of `sort` into this script to achieve what you want.

```
sort <inputfile> | python merger.py
```

Input:

```
<abc>  <anything2> <anything3>
<_901>  <first> <something1>
<_905>  <second> <something2>
<_910>  <anything> <something3>
<_901>  <second> <something4>
<_905>  <first> <something6>
<_901>  <third> <something5>
<_905>  <third> <something7>
```

Output:

```
<_901> <something1> <something4> <something5>
<_905> <something6> <something2> <something7>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you some ideas.  I've used some things from a David Beazely lecture on [Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/).  As your file is large I'm storing the `<something>` values in separate files. You might be able to append them to a list/dict; I'm not sure.  The opening, appending to and closing of files each time seems pretty inefficient to me but I can't think of anything else.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from StringIO import StringIO
import re
import os
import glob

#for generator details see see http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

def gen_grep_groups(pat, lines):

    patc = re.compile(pat)
    for line in lines:
        match = patc.search(line)
        if match:
            yield match.groups()

def logme(pairs, ext='.special_list'):
    for name, thing in pairs:
        #there must be a better way than opening and closing each time
        f = open(name + ext,'a')
        f.writelines(thing +'\n')
        f.close()


data = StringIO("""<abc>  <anything2> <anything3>.
<_901>  <first> <something1>.
<_905>  <second> <something2>.
<_910>  <anything> <something3>.
<_901>  <second> <something4>.
<_905>  <first> <something6>.
<_901>  <third> <something5>.
<_905>  <third> <something7>.""")

#for a file use data = open(filename)



pat = r'<(.+?)>\s+<(?:first|second|third)>\s+<(.+?)>'
ext = ".special_list"
#patternc = re.compile(pattern)

for f in glob.glob('*'+ ext):
    os.remove(f) #remove any existing files

pairs = gen_grep_groups(pat,data)
logme(pairs, ext)


for filename in glob.glob('*'+ ext):
    #do what you want in here    
    name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    print(name)
    f = open(filename,'r')    
    print(f.read())
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For a file this large, it might be appropriate to read in in multiple passes.

First, read the lines and store the key field together with the line numbers (or maybe better: file positions) where the data live:

```
pos = {}
filepos = file.tell()
for line in file:
    sline = line.split()
    pos.setdefault(sline[0], []).append(filepos)
    filepos.file.tell() # for the next read
```

Now you have a dict like, say, {'': [0], <_901>: [25, 87], ...}

Now you can iterate over the dict and do

```
for key, fileposes in pos.iteritems():
    if len(fileposes) == 1:
        file.seek(fileposes[0])
        print file.readline()
    else:
        outlinedata = []
        for filepos in fileposes:
            file.seek(fileposes[0])
            line = file.readline()
            sline = line.split()
            outlinedata.append(sline[2])
        print key, " ".join(outlinedata)
```

(But I am not sure if `tell/seek` on one hand and linewise reading and buffering of the file won't interfere with each other...)